# Formio Angular, how to emit an event?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formio

I'm looking to emit the event 'editGridSaveRow', so far I got this working

```html
<formio 
 [form]='form' 
 [submission]='submission' 
 (submit)="test($event)">
</formio>
```

(test function fires a message alert only), but when I try this, nothing happens

```html
<formio 
 [form]='form' 
 [submission]='submission' 
 (editGridSaveRow)="test($event)">
</formio>
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

PD: [here](https://help.form.io/developers/form-renderer) events list documentation, where editGridSaveRow it's listed

Answer (score 0):

Well there's no way to accomplish that, on my research I landed in this [page](https://github.com/formio/angular/wiki/Form-Renderer), there no event "editGridSaveRow" for formio-angular (scroll down to "output events").

I was looking for accomplish to submit only added and edited rows in editGrid, so finally I compared submission json data with submitted ones and get the difference.

Greetings!